# Are Quidditch deaths mentioned?

Tags: harry-potter, quidditch

The movies show players miraculously falling into soft things and avoiding certain death. Harry is also shown speeding outside the arena (maybe the basement) where he could ram into a wooden beam. And bludgeons.

The game seems so extremely dangerous that parents should be concerned and deaths should be mentioned frequently. Are deaths mentioned in canon? Or are there very good safety measures that can make it safe?

Comment: Dumbledore slows Harry's fall to save him in PoA.

Comment: @Bellerophon Seems like a one-off. What happened to other players who had potentially deadly falls?

Comment: @aitchnyu - It's only happened twice in cannon, and both players had their falls magically slowed and survived.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A referee died in the mid-1300s

> *Refereeing a Quidditch match was once a task for only the bravest
>   witches and wizards. Zacharias Mumps tells us that **a Norfolk referee
>   called Cyprian Youdle died during a friendly match between local
>   wizards in 1357.***
>
> <sub><sup>Quidditch Through the Ages</sup></sub>

Harry notes that Quidditch-related deaths (among players) are vanishingly rare

> *Harry learnt that there were seven hundred ways of committing a
>   Quidditch foul and that all of them had happened during a World Cup
>   match in 1473; that Seekers were usually the smallest and fastest
>   players and that most serious Quidditch accidents seemed to happen to
>   them; that **although people rarely died playing Quidditch**, referees had
>   been known to vanish and turn up months later in the Sahara Desert.*
>
> <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone - Chapter 11: Quidditch</sup></sub>

---

With reference to injuries, on at least one occasion a wizard is subject to an impact that would have probably killed a muggle. Trained mediwizards are on hand to ensure that he makes a full recovery

> ‘It’s time out!’ yelled Bagman’s voice. ‘As trained mediwizards hurry onto the pitch to examine Aidan Lynch!’
>   ‘He’ll be OK, he only got ploughed!’ Charlie said reassuringly to Ginny...
>
> <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire - Chapter 8: The Quidditch World Cup</sup></sub>

Comment: If the referee job takes the most guts, have there been more referee deaths?

Comment: @aitchnyu - That's the only one mentioned in the text. It's noted that they often suffer injuries and get hexed by players and fans.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what Wood has to say about it:

> "Er -- have the Bludgers ever killed anyone?" Harry asked, hoping he sounded offhand.
>
> "Never at Hogwarts. We've had a couple of broken jaws but nothing worse than that."

That implies that they do exist and have happened.

It makes sense; if [people have died from baseball](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ray_Chapman), they can certainly die by Quidditch.

[The wiki](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Death) says:

> Quidditch accidents, and misused magic, are also clearly capable of causing death, and Quidditch accidents in particular are described as having done so.

Comment: The wiki seems to be spouting a load of crap without any foundation

Comment: @Valorum And this is different from normal because what?

Comment: By quoting it as fact, you give it credence that it doesn't deserve.

Comment: I simply quoted it.  Nothing in my answer says it's a fact.  Your answer does go in the direction of confirming it, though.  Sort of.

Comment: I've (reluctantly) downvoted. A wiki quote without justification is merely a fan-theory. If I could be bothered to log in, I'd go and delete that sentence entirely.

Comment: @Valorum  OK, Cool

Comment: The Wood quote is not a suitable proof of Bludger related deaths. We can only speculate about Wood's true intentions, but it is just as likely that he just wanted Harry to be careful around Bludgers by scaring him a little.